# Layout is not floating above keyboard in Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a layout which has two edit texts and horizontal scroll bar with some icons in a fragment.

The horizontal scroll view is permanently fixed to the bottom of the parent using relative layout constraints.

When an edit is clicked, the soft keyboard appears by default.
When that happens, I need the horizontal scroll view to float above the soft keyboard so that everyone can use it.

I have added the following line to the AndroidManifest.xml file to the activity containing the fragment

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

The view still doesn't work as expected.

How do I fix this?

**Current Screen :**

**Current Screen without keyboard**
[[Current Screen w/o keyboard][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhcIo.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhcIo.png)

**Current Screen with keyboard**
[[Current Screen with keyboard][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFR9T.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFR9T.png)

**Expected Screens**

**Expected Screen without keyboard**
[[Expected Screen w/o keyboard][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf0jN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf0jN.png)

**Expected screen with keyboard**
[[Exoected Screen with keyboard][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGj05.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGj05.png)

And here is the **fragment xml** file.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <io.github.mthli.knife.KnifeText
        android:id="@+id/edt_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title_notes_add"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="Content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:historyEnable="true"
        app:historySize="20" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/title_notes_add"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="Title"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/undo"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_undo" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/redo"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_redo" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/bold"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_format_bold" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/italic"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_format_italic" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/underline"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_format_underlined" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/strikethrough"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_strikethrough" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/bullet"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_format_list_bulleted" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/quote"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_format_quote" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/link"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_insert_link" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/clear"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_format_clear" />

        </LinearLayout>    
    </HorizontalScrollView>       
</RelativeLayout>
```

Where have I gone wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: Make your `EditText` height `match_parent` with rule above `HorizontalScrollView`.

Comment: But the edit text is supposed to be a one-liner. Making it match parent would span it across the screen and that isn't what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this in fragment call on each onCreateView

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: 'SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE: Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a line in the manifest to adjust the screen visibility in an Activity.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```

So the activity tag in Manifest would be like this:

```
<activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan" 
   android:label="@string/app_name" >
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work man. My code is in a Fragment in an Activity if that helps

Comment: @sanoop sandy I had also tried but not worked for fragment

Comment: @SriramR for Fragment u need to do it programmatically.
Try this 
`getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);`